# Vuej.js debug, Google Chrome crash

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, vue.js, debugging, phpstorm

I am having problems with select in vue, even in the simplest example.
I create a project using the `vue init webpack-simple` command.
I do not create anything, just edit the source App.vue to the following form
App.vue:

```js
<template>
        <div id="app">
            <div class="Test">
                <div style="padding: 10px">
                    <select name="LeaveType" v-model="selectData" @change="selectAction">
                        <option>First</option>
                        <option>Second</option>
                        <option>Third</option>
                        <option>Fourth</option>
                    </select>
                    selectData = {{selectData}}
                </div>
                <div style="padding: 10px">
                    <input v-model="inputData" >
                    inputData = {{inputData}}
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </template>

    <script>

        export default {
            name: 'app',

            data() {
                return {
                    selectData: "Second",
                    inputData: "hello"
                }
            },
            props: {},
            watch: {
                selectData: function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    console.log("watch selectData ( newValue = ", newValue, " )");
                },
                inputData: function (newValue, oldValue) {
                    console.log("watch inputData ( newValue = ", newValue, " )");
                },
            },
            methods: {
                selectAction() {
                    console.log("selectAction");
                },
                inputAction() {
                    console.log("inputAction");
                }
            },


        }
    </script>

    <style>
        #app {
            font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
            -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
            -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
            text-align: center;
            color: #2c3e50;
            margin-top: 60px;
        }

        h1, h2 {
            font-weight: normal;
        }

        ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            padding: 0;
        }

        li {
            display: inline-block;
            margin: 0 10px;
        }

        a {
            color: #42b983;
        }
    </style>
```

I start the server `npm run dev`

When I start debugging this code (using PhpStorm or chrome devtools, it doesn't matter), putting breakpoints on the lines with `console.log`. By changing select in the browser, I get to my breakpoints.

[image]

In the selectAction method and in **watch - selectData**, but if you press F9, i.e. Further, the browser page drops.

---

[image]
That is, any debug caused by **select**'th causes the page to fall.
Moreover, without debug the page does not fall, everything works fine, not a single error is output to the console.
The **Watch** connected with **input** also works without crashes, both in debug mode and without it.
Tell me, please, what could be the problem? I tried on 2 computers, on Windows and on ubunt, the result is the same.

### [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/practical-fire-mgnjj?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Does your codesandbox crash for you as well, because that works just fine here.

Comment: @Sumurai8, page crash only in debug mode( in phpstorm with JavaScript Debbug, and also in chrome devtools). In "codesandbox" I did not get this error, because I don’t know how to debug there =)

Comment: Have you tried to debug with all your browser extensions disabled?

Comment: reproduced the issue in Chrome Dev Tools using your app. Unfortunately Chrome debug logs don't give any clue on what's going on. I'd suggest reporting this issue to Google team

Comment: @Sumurai8
I found out the following. I made the example even simpler, added everything to a single file, you can immediately run and check.
https://pastebin.com/GEvHwVCV
I started the virtual machine. On version 76 of Google Chrome, everything works fine. At 79 (the last at the moment) an error occurs in debug mode. Yes, I will try to create issue.

Comment: @lena, I found out the following. I made the example even simpler, added everything to a single file, you can immediately run and check.
https://pastebin.com/GEvHwVCV
I started the virtual machine. On version 76 of Google Chrome, everything works fine. At 79 (the last at the moment) an error occurs in debug mode. Yes, I will try to create issue.